# Pandas slicing along multiindex and separate indices

Tags: python, pandas

I've started using Pandas for some large Datasets and mostly it works really well. There are some questions I have regarding the indices though

1. I have a MultiIndex with three levels - let's say a, b, c. How do I slice along index a - I just want the values where a = 5,  7, 10, 13. Doing df.ix[[5, 7, 10, 13]] does not work as pointed out in the documentation
2. I need to have different indices on a DF - can I create these multiple indices and not associate them to a dataframe and use them to give me back the raw ndarray index?
3. Can I slice a MultiIndex on its own not in a series or Dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think you could include a construction for a sample `df` for this example?

Comment: I created a github issue to examine in more detail: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2598

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first part, you can use boolean indexing using [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#reconstructing-the-level-labels):

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('a').isin([5, 7, 10, 13])]
```

For the second two, you can inspect the [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) object by calling:

```
df.index
```

*(and this can be inspected/sliced.)*

Comment: brilliant! so I still have one problem. I can slice on multiindex, but I give it a raw index and it gives me back a tuple. I want it the other way around, so: 
    myindex[1, 2, 4]

Comment: @WolfgangKerzendorf So you want it exported to an array? I think the issue is that behind the scenes pandas stores using indices of .level, and doesn't store this array... I will take another look. Hopefully there is a better way than `np.array(map(np.array, df.index.values))` (!)

Comment: So I found that index.get_loc is similar to what I want. It translates from a key to an actual location - but it is not as useful as the .ix notation of a series. For now I think i will just do my_index = Series(arange(len(df)), index=myselectedindex)

Comment: df.index.get_level_values('a') gives back an array which doesn't have a method isin.

Comment: @WolfgangKerzendorf what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @WolfgangKerzendorf In `0.10` get_level_values returns an Index rather than an array, which has a `isin` method :)

Comment: no i'm on 0.9.1, but will upgrade. Thanks - I will update the answer ( I realized that I can do that).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: This answer for pandas versions lower than 0.10.0 only:**

Okay @hayden had the right idea to start with:

An index has the method `get_level_values()` which returns, however, an array (in pandas versions < 0.10.0). The `isin()` method doesn't exist for arrays but this works:

```
from pandas import lib
lib.ismember(df.index.get_level_values('a'), set([5, 7, 10, 13])
```

That only answers question 1 - but I'll give an update if I crack 2, 3 (half done with @hayden's help)